# What is the point of "typal" computation rules?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

The (recently created) page titled [integers type](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/integers+type) on ncatlab.org, in the section "As the inductive type generated by an element and an equivalence of types", gives two different forms of the computation rules:

[image]

It appears that the "typal computation rules" are just the judgmental computation rules but with propositional instead of judgmental equality. But what is the point of that? Why give two different sets of rules? Wouldn't having a judgmental equality always be more useful?

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage I can think of is that it is easy for a user to add the latter to a proof assistant. Many proof assistants allow you to add 'axioms,' but adding judgmental equalities is a more difficult proposition, because it can require some care to keep the system functioning properly. So, a user can manually add the integers with the latter rules themselves, even if the system doesn't support the judgmental rules.

In many cases it's possible to add enough axioms so that you can manually prove that everything is 'identical' to a canonical term, even though your axioms don't actually compute at all. For some people, that might be good enough. If you're doing everything on paper, the difference might matter even less, because nothing is automating the judgmental equality anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to have typal computation rules is that it might be the case that they hold in some model but the definitional rules don't.  For instance, the higher inductive types constructed in models for higher categories in https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07088 satisfy the computation rule for path-constructors only typally.